# how to generate combination of number length 2 in asp.net c#

Tags: combinations, permutation, probability

I have 1-9 digit number and want to generate probability (combination) of number without duplicate and with duplicate.

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

I need the output to be like this:

```
{1,2}{1,3}{1,4}{2,1}{2,3}{2,4}{3,1}{3,2}{3,4}{1,1}{2,2}{3,3}{4,4}
```

Comment: Do you want `{4,1}{4,2}{4,3}` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.size() ; i ++){
for(int j = i + 1; j < array.size() ;j++)
 {
    int first = array[i];
    int second = array[j];
    //Do someting.
 }
}
```